# Animate text like marquee which roll up from bottom to top and goes left

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, marquee

I am Developing an ios application where i am stuck with the marquee text bottom to top animation.I am able to scroll text like marquee using below code

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CBAutoScrollLabel *autoScrollLabel;

```
    self.autoScrollLabel.text = @"Some text here some text here some text here Some text here some text here some text here Some text here";
    self.autoScrollLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.autoScrollLabel.labelSpacing = 35; // distance between start and end labels
    self.autoScrollLabel.pauseInterval = 1.7; // seconds of pause before scrolling starts again
    self.autoScrollLabel.scrollSpeed = 30; // pixels per second
    self.autoScrollLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; // centers text when no auto-scrolling is applied
    self.autoScrollLabel.fadeLength = 10.f;
    self.autoScrollLabel.scrollDirection = CBAutoScrollDirectionLeft;
    [self.autoScrollLabel observeApplicationNotifications];
```

but now,how to roll up this text from bottom to top and goes left like marquee.
Any help would appreciated.
Thanks !!

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. I suppose you are using this class https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel ? 

So your text scrolls in a loop from right to left. What exactly do you want the text to do? Loop from bottom to top? It looks like CBAutoScrollLabel has only options for left and right scrolling, no up or down.

Comment: @MattiJokipii yes,you are right,i want loop from bottom to top and then scrolls to left like marquee..Then i guess i am going wrong..can you help me to achieve this ?!